# SQLite table not created

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have in my viewDidLoad() the below codes:

```
// Create a string containing the full path to the sqlite.db inside the documents folder
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sqlite.db"];

// Check to see if the database file already exists
bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

// Open the database and store the handle as a data member
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Create the database if it doesn't yet exists in the file system
    if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
    {
        // Create the PERSON table
        const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, BIRTHDAY DATE)";
        char *error;
        if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            // Create the ADDRESS table with foreign key to the PERSON table
            sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADDRESS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, STREETNAME TEXT, STREETNUMBER INT, PERSONID INT, FOREIGN KEY(PERSONID) REFERENCES PERSON(ID))";
            if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Database and tables created.");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
        }
    }
}

sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
```

And I am expecting that both tables are created in the folder /Users/*******/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/*******/Documents/.

But when I went to that folder and type sqlite3 and .schema, nothing shows up. 
I did see that sqlite.db is created in that folder though.

Do you know why?

Comment: Which of your `NSLog()`s are executed? Is "Database and tables created" reported? If no log message is printed, then your code didn't try to create the table because the db already existed.

Comment: log says "Database and tables created".

Comment: I found out the issue: in the terminal, I should rather enter the command "sqlite3 sqlite.db" than only "sqlite3".

Answer (score 0):

after copying the db , 
create table programmatically ..it will work for sure!!!!